# Eclipse Java project to runnable EXE

Tags: eclipse, jar, exe

I've been looking around for an answer for almost a week now, but I cannot seem to find the correct one. So I've built a GUI java application on Eclipse. I have Java JDK version 1.8.0-45 and referenced around 4 libraries to my application. I want to be able to create either a .jar file or a .exe file(s) that will run on any other computer.

So I've gotten a couple of solutions. I've tried JSmooth, Advanced Installed 12.2, Launch4J and every single application works. I double click on the generated files, and it runs perfectly on my computer. Even just exporting a runnable jar file from eclipse runs perfect on mine. But here's where I'm running into issues. If I take the generated jar/exe file to another computer, it doesn't work.

I thought that other computers didn't have a valid JRE, so I downloaded and installed Java JRE 1.8, and it doesn't work.

I"ve used Launch4J and even made sure to bundle the JRE with the jar, but it doesnt work.

I imported the entire eclipse project to Advanced Installer, made a .MSI installer including the jar and the JRE but it doesn't work.

I've used JSmooth, to generate the exe, and it doesnt work.

Reiterating, everything works on my computer. But what doesnt work is when I take the generated exe file to another computer and double click on the files, nothing happens. I don't see any GUI window or any JFrames. Absolutely nothing happens.

So if anyone could point me to a direction, or tell me what I'm not doing or what I'm doing wrong, it would be really appreciated. I've done my research for quite a bit, but I'm getting nowhere. HELP!

Comment: Provide more details than just "it doesn't work."

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had mentioned again. By "it doesn't work" I mean when I double click it, nothing happens. I don't see any error messages or any windows or anything at all. Literally nothing happens when I double click it.

Comment: 1. Can you see any related processes eg. java(w).exe on the computers you try to launch it (in task manager or Process Explorer)?
2. With runnable JAR try executing it from command line with `java.exe -jar your.jar` and see what happens. Are there any errors? Is the process running?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Apparently I was running into a version mismatch issue. Compiled with JDK 1.6 and it worked flawlessly!